# Relation between $G$-modules and $KG$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734957/is-there-any-difference-between-a-g-module-and-a-kg-module) the following definitions of a ring module and a $G$-module where given:

> **Definition 1**: Let $R$ be a ring with multiplicative identity $1$. A left $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ with a mapping from $R\times M$ to $M$, $(r,x)\mapsto rx$, such that
>
> 1. $r(x+y)=rx+ry,$
> 2. $(r+s)x=rx+sx,$
> 3. $(rs)x=r(sx),$
> 4. $1x=x.$

> **Definition 2**: Let $V$ be a vector space and $G$ be a group with identity $\epsilon$. Then $V$ is a $G$-module if there is a multiplication, $g\mathbf{v}$, of elements of $V$ by elements of $G$ such that
>
> 1. $g\mathbf{v}\in V$,
> 2. $g(c\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{w})=c(g\mathbf{v})+d(g\mathbf{w})$,
> 3. $(gh)\mathbf{v}=g(h\mathbf{v})$,
> 4. $\epsilon\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$,
>
> for all $g,h\in G;\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in V$; and scalars $c,d$ of the field.

The OP then writes "*Any vector space is an abelian group and the group algebra $KG$ is a ring. We can therefore consider $V$ as a $KG$-module satisfying the conditions in Definition 1, and it is easy to see that it then also satisfies the conditions in definition 2.*" It was concluded that there is no real difference between a $G$-module and a $KG$-module.
My questions:

1. It is easy to see that conditions 3 and 4 in Definition 2 are identical to conditions 3 and 4 of Definition 1, but how does the second condition in Definition 2 follow from Definition 1?
2. Assume we go in the opposite direction, starting with a $G$-module and want to show that we can consider it an $R$-module with $R$ being the group algebra $KG$. We can see that condition 1 in Definition 1 follows from condition 2 in Definition 2 by letting $c=d=1$, but how does condition 2 in Definition 1 follow from Definition 2?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that these are different terms, there is just a natural correspondence between them. Of course condition $2$ in the first definition can't follow directly from the second definition, as we don't even have an addition operation in $G$, but we do in $KG$.

If $V$ is a $G$-module, then we can naturally give it a $KG$-module structure as follows:

$(\sum\limits_{g\in G} k_gg)v=\sum\limits_{g\in G}k_g(gv)$

Where $gv$ is the action of the element $g\in G$ on the vector $v\in V$. Now just check by hand that all the conditions of a $KG$-module are satisfied. In particular, condition $2$ is really straightforward.

Conversely, if $M$ is a $KG$ module then since we have a natural embedding $K\subseteq KG$, we get a $K$-vector space structure on $M$ by restricting the scalars from $KG$ to $K$. And since also $G\subseteq KG$, restricting the scalars from $KG$ to $G$ gives $M$ a structure of a $G$-module. In other words, $gx$ (for $g\in G, x\in M$) is defined as we view $g$ as an element of $KG$. Again, check that all the required conditions are satisfied. For example:

$c(gx)=(cg)x=(gc)x=g(cx), \ \ c\in K, g\in G, x\in M$

This just follows from condition $3$ in definition $1$.

Finally, it can be checked that what we defined here is indeed a bijective correspondence between representations of $G$ and $KG$-modules. It also preserves many properties. (for example, simple modules correspond to irreducible representations)

Comment: So, for example, the first condition of Definition 1 follows by $\sum_{g}k_gg(v+w)=\sum_{g}k_g(g(v+w))=\sum_gk_g(gv+gw)=\sum_g(k_ggv+k_ggw)=\sum_gk_ggv+\sum_gk_ggw$?

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's it. I would write the left hand side as $(\sum\limits_{g\in G}k_gg)(v+w)$ in order to make it look exactly like in the condition, but I guess that was what you meant anyway.

Comment: Yes, more exactly $(\sum_{g}k_gg)(v+w)=\sum_{g}k_g(g(v+w))=\sum_gk_g(gv+gw)=\sum_g(k_g(gv)+k_g(gw))=\sum_gk_g(gv)+\sum_gk_g(gw)=(\sum_gk_gg)v+(\sum_gk_gg)w.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

> how does the second condition in Definition 2 follow from Definition 1?

In definition 1, from the first condition you get $r(x+y)=rx+ry$ for every $r,s\in KG$. Restricting to elements $r$ of the form $1_K\cdot g$, and identifying them with their counterparts in $G$, you clearly have the second condition in Definition 2.

> Assume we go in the opposite direction, starting with a $$
> -module and want to show that we can consider it an $$
> -module with $$ being the group algebra $$ [...] how does condition 2 in Definition 1 follow from Definition 2?

It does not (cannot) follow *directly* from Definition 2 because Definition 2 makes no reference to a second operation between elements.  It works because the definition of addition in $KG$ is the linear extension of that defined by the action of $G$ on $V$, and that extension satisfies condition 2 in Definition 1 by virtue of the way addition is defined (in addition to the axioms in Definition 2.)

---

A more consistent way of saying it would be:

> **Definition 1**: Let $R$ be a $K$ algebra with multiplicative identity $1$. A left $R$-module is a vector space $V$ with a mapping $B:R\times V\to V$, $(r,x)\mapsto rx$, such that
>
> 1. $B$ is bilinear (that is $B(x,-)$ is a linear transformation for any $x$ and $B(-,y)$ is a linear transformation for any $y$)
> 2. $B(rs,x)=B(r,B(s,x))$ for all $r,s\in R$ and $x\in V$
> 3. $B(1,x)=x$ for all $x\in V$

> **Definition 2**: Let $G$ be a group with multiplicative identity $\epsilon$. A left $G$-module is a vector space $V$ with a mapping $B:G\times V\to V$, $(r,x)\mapsto rx$, such that
>
> 1. $B(g,-)$ is a linear transformation for any $g\in G$
> 2. $B(gh,x)=B(g,B(h,x))$ for all $g,h\in G$ and $x\in V$
> 3. $B(\epsilon,x)=x$ for all $x\in V$

As you can see there is very little difference between the two, and then thing that makes it work for $R=KG$ is that Conditions 1+2 of Definition 2 make the linear extension of multiplication to $KG$ work.